# New webpage not being shown

Tags: html, browser-cache

I have a web development question.

Sometimes, if I place a new version of a webpage on a webserver, and I browse to this webpage, the new page is not shown. Instead the old page is shown, from the cached page from a previous browse to the webpage.

How can I get the new page to always be shown? Is there a tag of some sort that I can use for this?

Comment: Check your caching HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tags you can use

See http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

There are similar HTTP headers that the web server can set as well.

Comment: Is it possible, via a tag, to check to see if the date of the page is newer than the cached version, and if it is, reload the page? Should this not be done by default?

Comment: @Simon: Yes; you should configure your server to correctly set `Last-Modified` or `ETag` caching headers, and set `Must-Revalidate`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify no caching and how long to cache individual files in .htaccess if you are using Apache. Typically you would disable caching on dynamic content and set caching limits to the usual update rate of images and static html. On my site I regenerate the static html every day so have set caching to 24 hours on .html and disabled caching on PHP scripts (these limits are specified in seconds - 1 day = 86,400 seconds):

```
# Set up caching on media files for 1 week
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>



# Set up 1 Day caching on site generated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html)$">
ExpiresDefault A86400
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic php
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

If you are just having problems testing changes to your html files, remember that you can usually force a browser to reload the page regardless of cache settings - [Ctrl][F5] under Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I think the server still haven't update the site. Just wait and see if it updates.

Comment: I do wait, yet the old page is still shown. If I manually refresh the page, the new page is shown.